# XSLT - output to html a specific XML element which contains formatted text - output should be same

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

I have an xml element which contains formatted text data :

```
   <MESSAGE>
      <TranslationReport>
Translation Report
==================
Contains errors ? true
Contains warnings ? false
There are 9 entries in the report
```

**I want the results of my xslt (output to html) to match the contents of TranslationReport EXACTLY.
Everything I do just takes a data (all in one line - see below). This seems easy, but I have searched in all of my books and everywhere else...**

> Translation Report ================== Contains errors ? true Contains
>   warnings ? false There are 9 entries in the report

Comment: I am able to produce the results you are looking for with a straight XSL transform, using for example http://www.shell-tools.net/index.php?op=xslt How are you rendering the results?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an `<xsl:output method="text"/>` [tag](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp) and/or enclosing the literal text in `<xsl:text>...</xsl:text>` [tags](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_text.asp)?

If you are rendering the results in HTML, the problem is that HTML does not render newlines without enclosing the output in a [tag like](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) `<pre>`. Output a `<pre>` tag wrapping your text output in your XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into may have to do with the fact that in XML, different forms of white space (linebreaks, spaces, etc.) are considered equivalent.  See this answer:  [Is it "bad practice" to be sensitive to linebreaks in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277/is-it-bad-practice-to-be-sensitive-to-linebreaks-in-xml-documents/7292#7292)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to render to html you have two options:

- use `pre` tag to render your text in the browser exactly as is.
- parse your text with some advanced XPath 2.0 function and handle each text line as required.

Here the first option silly example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="MESSAGE/TranslationReport">
        <html>
            <body>
                <pre>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </pre>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the second option we will parse your text with the XPath 2.0 function `tokenize`, splitting all lines and wrapping each one with the eanted tag.

This is the silly example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="MESSAGE/TranslationReport">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\n')
                    [not(position()=(1,last()))]">
                    <p class="TranslationReport">
                        <xsl:value-of select=".[position()]"/>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the second case the output will be:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="TranslationReport">Translation Report</p>
        <p class="TranslationReport">==================</p>
        <p class="TranslationReport">Contains errors ? true</p>
        <p class="TranslationReport">Contains warnings ? false</p>
        <p class="TranslationReport">There are 9 entries in the report</p>
    </body>
</html>
```